# Passing a QVector pointer as an argument

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qvector

1) I want to pass a the pointer of a QVector to a function and then do things with it. I tried this:

```
void MainWindow::createLinearVector(QVector<float> *vector, float min, float max )
{
    float elementDiff=(max-min)/(vector->size()-1);

    if(max>min) min -= elementDiff;
    else        min += elementDiff;

    for(int i=0; i< vector->size()+1 ; i++ )
    {
        min += elementDiff;
        *(vector+i) = min; //Problematic line
    }

}
```

However the compiler gives me  **"no match for operator ="** for the `*(vector+i) = min;` line. What could be the best way to perform actions like this on a QVector?

2) The function is supposed to linearly distribute values on the vector for a plot, in a way the matlab : operator works, for instance vector(a:b:c). What is the simpliest and best way to perform such things in Qt?

**EDIT:**

With help from here the initial problem is solved. :)

I also improved the metod in itself. The precision could be improved a lot by using linear interpolation instead of multiple additions like above. With multiple addition an error is accumulating, which is eliminated in large part by linear interpolation.

Btw, the if statement in the first function was unecessary and possible to remove by just rearranging stuff a little bit even in the multiple addition method.

```
void MainWindow::createLinearVector(QVector<double> &vector, double min, double max )
{
    double range = max-min;
    double n =   vector.size();

    vector[0]=min;

    for(int i=1; i< n ; i++ )
    {
        vector[i] = min+ i/(n-1)*range;
    }
}
```

I considered using some enchanced loop for this, but would it be more practical? 
With for instance a foreach loop I would still have to increment some variable for the interpolation right? And also make a conditional for skipping the first element?

Comment: You are trying to assign a `float` to a `QVector`. That isn't allowed, but is it really what you want to do?

Comment: I want to place a float a certain place in the QVector. This is allowed by [] operator, but not when "vector" is a pointer. 
I also tried to pass by reference. Then the [] was ok, but calling by &myVector wasn't allowed then instead.

Comment: Then don't pass a pointer. Or ask how to call overloaded operators from pointers.

Comment: Hm, could be worth a checkup. If you have some nice link, plz post :) 

Remade the function again to take a reference and tried to call it with myVector.data(). The function compiled but not the call to it.

Comment: Please leave a comment under the answers if they are all wrong. Otherwise, please select an answer.

Answer (score 5):

> I want to place a float a certain place in the QVector.

Then use this:

```
(*vector)[i] = min; //Problematic line
```

A vector is a pointer to a QVector, `*vector` will be a QVector, which can be indiced with `[i]` like any QVector. However, due to precedence, one needs parentheses to get the order of operations right.

Comment: IMO, using foreach would be more natural in a Qt software with Qt containers, in which case the indexing is not a concern anymore. :-)

Comment: That probably true, for loops are a hazzle. However, the flexibility provided is nice.

Comment: @user3050215: what flexibility needed for your code? A foreach does the most Qt'ish job for this task IMO. It also dismisses the concern about indexing. :-)

Comment: @LaszloPapp This is the minimal edit to make his code work. Reviewing the style is more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: In my opinion, it is better to point out any mistake in the code. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think, first u need use the Mutable iterator for this stuff: [Qt doc link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmutablevectoriterator.html)

Something like this:

```
QMutableVectorIterator<float> i(vector);
i.toBack();
while (i.hasPrevious())
    qDebug() << i.{your code}
```

Comment: Thats interesting! However, probably not necessary?

"An alternative to using iterators is to use index positions. Most QVector member functions take an index as their first parameter, making it possible to access, insert, and remove items without using iterators."

http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qmutablevectoriterator.html

Comment: You should always prefer iterators to indexes because they prevent off-by-one errors.

Comment: @SimonWarta: IMO, an iterator here is an unnecessary overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Right, so it does not make much sense to use a QVector pointer in here. These are the reasons for that:

- Using a reference for the method parameter should be more C++'ish if the implicit sharing is not fast enough for you.
- Although, most of the cases you would not even need a reference when just passing arguments around without getting the result back in the same argument (i.e. output argument). That is because *QVector is [implicitly shared](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/shared.html) and the copy only happens for the write as per documentation. Luckily, the syntax will be the same for the calling and internal implementation of the method in both cases, so it is easy to change from one to another.
- Using smart pointers is preferable instead of raw pointers, but here both are unnecessarily complex solutions in my opinion.

So, I would suggest to refactor your code into this:

```
void MainWindow::createLinearVector(QVector<float> &vector, float min, float max)
{
    float elementDiff = (max-min) / (vector.size()-1);

    min += ((max>min) ? (-elementDiff) : elementDiff)

    foreach (float f, vector) {
        min += elementDiff;
        f = min;
    }
}
```

Note that I fixed up the following things in your code:

- Reference type parameter as opposed to pointer
- "->" member resolution to "." respectively
- Ternary operation instead of the unnatural if/else in this case
- Qt's foreach instead of low-level indexing in which case your original point becomes moot

This is then how you would invoke the method from the caller:

```
createLinearVector(vector, fmin, fmax);
```

Comment: there is no QVector reference here so any updates to vector are lost (which is not what he want)

Comment: Thanks! I should probably study the enchanced looping alternatives more, as I'm only used to the alternatives in low level embedded programming. 
Regarding the ternary operation, I don't know. It doesn't feel like it makes the code more readable nor faster, but maybe it's better when getting used to it. 

I realised there is another method to do what I intended, posted it in the topic.

Comment: @user3050215: you can keep the if/else if you wish. That is not the main point for solving your issue. That was just an additional suggestion. It does make the code shorter at the very least. The rest is probably personal taste about it.

Comment: @user3050215: btw, you seem to have 6 questions, but no selected answers. Please read the following url for details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Aha. Many good answers though, couldn't give the whole credit to a single answer.

Comment: @user3050215: choose one which you think is the best (Qt) code with the best explanation around. At least, that is how I would personally do it. You can still upvote the rest. :-) This way, you can avoid people looking into this thread needlessly since they will see the issue is "resolved".

Comment: @user3050215: please select an answer if your problem is resolved. Do not leave questions open. It is a very bad practice.